# En "hacer dormir a un recien nacido", ¿qué es "dormir" sintácticamente?

Tags: sintaxis, infinitivo, categorías-gramaticales, complemento-directo

En la frase "yo hago tareas" , si entiendo correctamente, "tareas" es el objeto directo de la oración. ¿Qué pasa cuando el verbo "hacer" en lugar de recibir un sustantivo recibe un verbo, como en la oración "hacer dormir a un recién nacido" ? Es "dormir" en esta frase un objeto directo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como se indica en [esta web sobre los usos del infinitivo](http://slllc.ucalgary.ca/AVal/505/AGUsosInfinitivo.html)

> El infinitivo en español ejerce funciones de SUSTANTIVO y por lo tanto puede funcionar como sujeto, complemento del verbo o modificador de nombre, adjetivo o adverbio.

Así que en "Hacer **dormir** a un recién nacido", El verbo "hacer" esta recibiendo un sustantivo. Entonces todo queda mucho más claro en ese análisis sintáctico...

Comment: Creo que tu análisis no es correcto. "hacer dormir" es frase verbal, equiparable a "acunar". Otro posible análisis es considerar el infinitivo como complemento predicativo objetivo, pero no creo que sea el caso con "hacer". Sí lo es con verbos de percepción, por ejemplo, podemos decir "ver dormir a un recién nacido" o "ver a un recién nacido dormir".

Comment: Seguramente tienes razón. Podría ser diferentes cosas. Yo entiendo que "Hacer dormir a un recién nacido" no es realmente una oración en sí (no más que "Hacer cena para dos"). Tendría más sentido algo como "Hacer dormir a un recién nacido **es** un arte" o "Hacer cena para dos **es** sencillo", donde el "hacer + infinitivo" funcionaría como complemento predicativo. Si dijeses "Me encanta _hacer dormir a un recién nacido_", la construcción tendría otra función sintáctica. Creo que simplemente ver 2 infinitivos seguidos confundía al OP y ver que el inf. puede funcionar como otras cosas le sirvió

Comment: Creo que **dormir** en este caso sustituye una frase como **que un recién nacido duerma**. Y entonces _hacer dormir_ en este caso es frase verbal donde _dormir_ ejerce función de sustantivo. Por ejemplo **hacer una cosa** ¿Qué cosa? _que el niño duerma_

Answer (score 4):

En línea con mi observación a la respuesta de Diego, encontramos en la *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española*, en su punto 26.5.1. El infinitivo con verbos de percepción y causación, lo siguiente:

> Han sido muy debatidas en todas las épocas la estructura e interpretación de las construcciones de infinitivo que dependen de verbos de percepción (*Vio a Rocio salir de su casa; Se oía a los frailes cantar gregoriano*) o de verbos de causación (*Hizo a Sofía leer en voz alta el documento; Déjame decirte una cosa*).
>
> **26.5.1a** La primera cuestión problemática es la función sintáctica que corresponde a los segmentos subrayados en el apartado anterior [para suplir el subrayado, los reitero a continuación: *salir de su casa, cantar gregoriano, leer en voz alta el documento, decirte una cosa*]. **Parece haber acuerdo actualmente en que se trata de complementos predicativos**, lo que se ve confirmado por el hecho de que alternan con adjetivos y otras categorías que desempeñan la misma función: *La vi sentarse Cf. La vi cansada; Hazlo menguar Cf. Hazlo más pequeño: Déjenlo descansar Cf. Déjenlo en paz.* [Las negritas son mías.]

Cabe recordar que en sintaxis llamamos complemento predicativo a aquella palabra o frase que, ubicada en el predicado (de allí el nombre), se refiere al sujeto (complemento predicativo subjetivo) o al objeto (complemento predicativo objetivo).

Por lo tanto, el infinitivo "dormir" en la frase en cuestión puede ser considerado como un complemento predicativo objetivo, obviamente en el contexto de una oración completa, pues se refiere al objeto directo "a un recién nacido".

Más adelante, en el punto 26.5.1f, encontramos esta alusión a lo que podríamos llamar una "frase verbal", denominada por la gramática como "predicado complejo" (a mi entender, por la tendencia a que ambos verbos aparezcan juntos):

> Es característica de los verbos de percepción y de los causativos la tendencia a constitutir un PREDICADO COMPLEJO con el infinitivo: *ver pasar, hacer temblar, oír entrar, etc.* Es habitual que el infinitivo aparezca junto al verbo principal, al menos en la lengua oral.

En este caso, concebida como una unidad, "hacer dormir" sería una frase verbal.