# Is this use of "hacerlo" wrong?

Tags: gramática

As I was writing for my Spanish course, I wrote the sentence:

> Juego al tenis, pero no **hacerlo** bien.

I interpret this to mean "I play tennis, but I don't do it well." However, it was marked wrong. Why is it incorrect?

Comment: Short short answer: you forgot to conjugate the second verb.  Minimalist correction: Juego al tenis, pero no bien.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is wrong. Realize (I know I'm pointing the obvious here) that

> hacerlo = **hacer** + lo.

The relevant part I want to point out is that you are using the verb `hacer` in infinitive, and that is not the verb tense you want to use (you would be saying the equivalent of "I play tennis, but I *to do* it not well").

One of the correct way of expressing it would be

> Juego al tenis, pero no **lo hago** bien.

That sentence is using a present form, and not an infinitive<sup>1</sup>. You could also have used

> Juego al tenis, pero no **sé** hacerlo bien.

Which is trickier, because now "saber" is the verb which goes in present tense and "hacerlo" is just a direct complement<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> You need to to move that pronoun. While you could have said "no *hágolo* bien" that would sound weird to most native speakers. Check other existing questions about pronouns.

<sup>2</sup> With another tricky stuff: the infinitive has many uses in Spanish ([can be used as a noun](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21332/5481)), so that verb "hacer" is the direct complement of `saber`.

Comment: Diego should you change CD by Direct Complement instead on the last sentence? One to say it all in English and two for readability.

Comment: Another alternative: *Sé jugar al tenis, pero no hacerlo bien* (literally: "I can play tennis, but not do it well").